# How to change .jenkins folder path on slave node to another directory value

Tags: jenkins

I've disk quota limitation problem on my home directory on my slave node, that's preventing jenkins to create its .jenkins on my home(slave node)

I tried changing - "Remote root directory"  value on slave configuration, but of no use.

Is there any method to change the .jenkins not on my home directory but on other path, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set the `JENKINS_HOME` environment variable as described in [the docs](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins).

Comment: Thank you for your time, I've tried changing the JENKINS_HOME value too, but no luck

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Root directory not writable: /login/myhome/.jenkins/cache/jars
 at hudson.remoting.FileSystemJarCache.<init>(FileSystemJarCache.java:62)
 at hudson.remoting.JarCache.getDefault(JarCache.java:39)
 ... 5 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /login/myhome/.jenkins: No space left on device`

Comment: Hi, of course you cant to write absolutely anything on the full disk, you need to free-up some space first, `jenkins_home` should be the right way to follow :)

Comment: Only my home directory is full, other mounts have space and jenkins_home didnt fix the issue. I tried jenkins_home with a different mount/path with plenty of space, but jenkins tries to create .jenkins on my home directory only.

Comment: It may still need to write there temporarily in order to move. Is it possible to remove some job history as indicated [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/215549798-Best-Strategy-for-Disk-Space-Management-Clean-Up-Old-Builds)? Another option is to "stop Jenkins completely, move the contents from old JENKINS_HOME to the new home, set the new JENKINS_HOME, and restart Jenkins."